# How to pass C++ pointers to to other cython objects

Tags: python, c++, cython

I still am having a very hard time figuring this out. Take this simple scenario.. in a file named PyFoo.pyx

```
cdef extern from "Foo.h" namespace "Foo":  
    cdef cppclass C_FOO:
        ...........

cdef class PythonFoo:
    C_FOO* pythonFoo
    def __cinit__(self):
        self.pythonFoo=new CFOO()
```

I do have a PyFoo.PXD also, that simply does this for a forward decl so other classes can see it

```
cdef class PythonFoo:
    C_FOO * pythonFoo
```

Now I have another class (in PyBar.pyx) that needs PythonFoo.pythonFoo as a member

```
cdef extern from "Bar.h" namespace "Bar":  
    cdef cppclass C_Bar:
         ThisFunctionNeeds(C_FOO*)
cimport PythonFoo        
cdef class PythonBar:
    C_Bar* pythonBar
    def __cinit__(self):
        self.pythonBar=new C_Bar()
    def SomeFunction(self,PythonFoo):
        ThisFunctionNeeds(PythonFoo.pythonFoo)
```

No matter how I try to cimport it, I get "PythonFoo not defined" (Because there is no **init** in the pxd file I guess) or I have to manually include the Foo.pyx, making this now a member of Bar.

Can someone please show me (with an example please) how this is supposed to work?

Thank you.

EDIT: PythonFoo and PythonBar are in separate modules in the package.

In a Python Tester, I try to use this

```
import PythonFoo
import PythonBar

foo=PythonFoo()
bar=PythonBar()
bar.SomeFunction(foo)
```

Here is where I get the "No module named 'PyFoo'

Comment: Is it a typo that you have `PyFoo` in the pyx and `Foo` in the pxd? Also, ["You don’t need to (and shouldn’t) declare anything in a declaration file public in order to make it available to other Cython modules"](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/sharing_declarations.html#the-cimport-statement) - import the module pyFoo instead.

Comment: Yes, it is a typo, but I hope the question still makes sence. The problem is, if I don't put anything in the pxd file,when I try to import pyFoo into pyBar, nothing is known about it. If I place the forward delaration into Foo.pxd, then I can import pyFoo, but when trying to run a python program, the error is "Can not find module pyFoo. I adjusted the above example to further illustrate.

Comment: The issue is I am not able to import the module, I have tried that too. Say PythonFoo is in a directory (from ".") Interfaces/Stuff, and PythonBar is in a directory (from ".") Interfaces/OtherStuff.   I always get the error "PythonFoo is not a cimported module"...

Comment: @MattOstlund shouldn't it be `from PyFoo cimport PythonFoo`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find why it would not work...  The actual directory of the module was not placed, as a matter of fact, the file was placed at a higher directory from the build directory.

I fixed it with a simple

sys.path.append('package_directory')

EDIT: I also found out why this was... I had an `__init__.py` in the same directory as my setup.py file, so the compiler thought that directory was part of the package.  I deleted the `__init__.py`, and I no longer needed to append the directory.

Comment: I don't see how having the `__init__.py` at the same dir as the `setup.py` could be a problem... but adding the package dir is surely important to `cimport`.

Comment: It's because the names were not qualified in this particular example.